# Use two different GitHub environment secrets in single action

Tags: github-actions

I have created GitHub Environment Secrets for staging and productions for example

```
Enviroment > Production  > DB_PASS
```

and

```
Enviroment > Staging  > DB_PASS
```

in my workflow I have

```
on:
 push:
    branches:
      - main
      - staging
jobs:
  deploy:
    environment: Production 
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Debug Secret 
      run: echo ${{ secrets.DB_PASS}}
```

How can I change the environment to Staging when branch merged is staging, probably by using
`gihub.ref` for the branch name. I tried passing the value dynamically to `environment` from the previous job using `needs.job1.outputs.output1` but it didn't work.

I found that some developer on Stackoverflow has suggested using a prefix in secret names
like

- PROD_DB_PASS
- STG_DB_PASS

but is there any better and cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Like you mentioned `github.ref` is probably the best way to go about it.

```yaml
on:
 push:
    branches:
      - main
      - staging
jobs:
  deploy-production:
    environment: Production 
    name: Deploy production
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' }}
    steps:
      - name: Debug Secret 
        run: echo ${{ secrets.DB_PASS }}

  deploy-staging:
    environment: Staging 
    name: Deploy staging
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging' }}
    steps:
      - name: Debug Secret 
        run: echo ${{ secrets.DB_PASS }}
```

Agreed there is a lot of duplicated code, but I think it is simpler, clearer and more reliable than dynamically passing the environment based on some previous job.

Comment: No problem. It true that despite the documentation quality, there is a lot of advanced possibilities that need reading between lines.

Comment: Yes that what I meant by "dynamically passing the environment based on some previous job". In any case it's pretty much equivalent and you can pick whichever one makes more sense to you. If you need more advanced patterns I started a small project recently https://github.com/benjamin-bergia/github-workflow-patterns

Comment: Thanks! @ITChap the only issue for me was that when I passed value dynamically it didn't work with a single syntax i.e. environment: {{ needs.getenv.outputs.env }}, it worked only when I used object syntax i.e. environment: name: {{ needs.getenv.outputs.env }}. I am not sure what's the reason behind this or it's a bug may be.

Comment: This is horrible. Imagine having 100 lines on each job, and 3 or 4 environments, you must then have 1000 lines action just because the environment cannot be set dynamically?

Comment: There is no details on the user actual setup. If we consider the info in the question: only two environments and maybe dissimilar steps in each jobs, I think it's a reasonable starting point. Obviously with the requirements you give I would do something very different. Maybe something like https://github.com/benjamin-bergia/github-workflow-patterns/blob/master/.github/workflows/matrix-objects.yml